# Setting Up New CentOS server - Partitions Sizes and File Systems

Tags: centos, partition

I'm responsible for setting up a new CentOS 7 server. It's my first time so I want to make sure I'm on the right track. After some research, I chose to have 6 partitions:

```
Partition | Type | Device Type | Mounted at

1 | ext4 | VLM | /    
2 | ext4 | Standard Partition | /boot
3 | ext4 | VLM | /home   
4 | ext4 | VLM | /var   
5 | ext4 | VLM | /usr    
6 | ext4 | VLM | /swap
```

In fact, the capacity is what I'm not sure of: (HDD: 1 TB)

```
/ 60 GB
/boot 1GB
/home 800GB
/var 20GB (since /var holds logs and databases)
/usr 20GB
/swap 2*RAM = 2*8 = 16GB
100 GB not allocated
```

I'm most concern about `/var` size, since I have no idea how big the database will be, I'm not sure how can I tell how much I should set it.

Comment: why not shrink /home to less, and add a /var/mysql ( /var/whatever) for databases ?

Comment: A basic CentOS 7 development system can run comfortably with 500MB /boot (enough for 8 copies of kernels and initramfs's) and 12GB for everything else. Disk is cheap, so you can triple these numbers if you want a cushion. Then you add swap space and space for users' files and software. You should **ask the users what they need**. Actually, ask them what they think they will need that will **cover them for the next year**, so that you don't have to keep increasing the space piecemeal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** You have not to use LVM for `/`  and `/boot` 
But DB: DB always be stored in /var such as mysql and psql, So need a big space for it.
You can create the following question from yourself:

1. Do we have syslog center?
2. Do we have more than 10 effective user account?
3. What's size of our memory? (for size of swap)
4. What do we have packages?
5. What's your hdd size?
6. How many we have db number?
   and so on....
   When you find logical answer to them , you can partion your hdd.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `/` on LVM and `/boot` is separate.